# InfoPath Form Library Form in Web Part

Tags: infopath, forms-services

How can I get an existing form library form (that is, one that has already been submitted) to display in a info path web part?

For form library forms, as distinct from list forms, I can only seem to get them to display in "new" or "submit" mode (even though I can hide the submit button).

I have a read-only view in my form, and in the web part I have set it to use this view.  How do I tell the web part what existing form I need?  I can't see where I can pass in the file name?

I know I can pass query string parameters to it (say, via the query string web part) and then use the web part connections feature to send this onto the info path web part and finally to the form itself.  But this does not link it to an existing form, in any way I can find, OOTB.  Am I supposed to use this to lookup the information in the form library and then populate the fields of the form (in code)?

Thanks for any help,

Richard

Answer (score 1):

On the page where you want the InfoPath form to display, create two web parts. The first is a standard list web part that exposes the library where you have your Infopath forms stored. The second is a form web part to expose an InfoPath form.

In the edit web part dialog, set the InfoPath web part to point to the same library (where you have your forms). Set the View to the read only view you created.

Then, create a connection (page edit, web part menu, connections) to send the row of data to the form web part you created to expose the InfoPath form.

When you select an item from list, the form will be displayed.

Answer (score 1):

This is horrible, but you could construct a "special version" of the InfoPath form that recieves data from the InfoPath Document Library, with a filter to pick the specific form in question, then in the form you can put "fx" or Rules to copy into each field from this Receive data source, using a filter on each to pull the exact InfoPath Document Library. This will probably only pull from fields that are promoted to be viewed as Meta Data Columns in Sharepoint. This InfoPath form would have no Save/close/Submit or any submit buttons etc. Probably don't want any views for the user to pick either (remove from info path menu).

Anyways, I said this was horrible, but it would probably work.

Answer (score 0):

You can select the form library you wish to use in the edit web part zone. I have added an image to illustrate, it's dutch but the selection menu is in the samen exact spot for your language.

Make sure you have enabled you form to be filled in using a browser. You can set this property in the second step of publishing your infopath form.

[image: Help]

Comment: nldev - I can get to that part just fine.  However the form is opening up in "submit" or "new" mode.  How can I pass in to the web part to show a previously submitted form?

Comment: Excuse me I understood your post wrong, i have looked and cannot think of any solution for your problem.

Answer (score 0):

> How can I get an existing form library form (that is, one that has
>   already been submitted) to display in a info path web part?

For me the answer seems to be in [Relinking forms which is , in this case Infopath Form webpart, to Infopath form template](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/infopath/archive/2006/11/01/relinking-forms-and-form-templates.aspx)

Answer (score 0):

Create a page and add InfoPath form webpart and save the page. Do not configure any properties for the webpart (library name or content type). Navigate to the page including your existing InfoPath form XmlLocation. eg. **http://siteurl/yourpage.aspx?XmlLocation=/sites/teamsites/TestFormLibrary/aaaaa.xml**

https://devdotnotes.wordpress.com/2012/01/29/sharepoint-caculated-column-and-hyperlink-no-workflow-or-script-needed/

follow this link if you want to build this url dynamically in your view.